# How to export .mtl files for 3D textured objects

Tags: graphics, textures

I would really like to deploy my textured 3D graphics in the web with [sketchfab](https://sketchfab.com) in my blog. Unfortunately, Mathematica only exports the *shape* of the 3d graphics, i.e. the .obj file, but omits the associated material file (.mtl) which is not generated.

Is there any way to accomplish my aim and deploy from Mathematica textured-graphics to sketchfab or any other standard textured material format? Perhaps someone has written a basic .mtl exporter?

Comment: Sketchfab supported formats: https://sketchfab.com/faq/upload#which-formats-are-supported. Mathematica 3D file formats: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/3DGeometryAndModelingFormats.html. Is there something you can use there? For example `.3DS` is supported in both

Comment: @blochwave Thanks for the comment. Yes I had already check that out. Supported model files include .3ds, .obj, .dae, .blend... But to add texture, Sketchfab requires a zip file combining both Model file AND Materials (.mtl), hence the .mtl file is required, without it there will be no rendered textures :(

Comment: I will note that unless the user specifies a texture using something like `PlotStyle->ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "WhiteMarble"}]`, it seems like Mathematica will create both of these files. However, if a texture is specified, it will only create the `.obj` file. (See documentation for `obj` format, including working examples. This is v10, not sure if same for v9.)

Comment: Great question! Shouldn't be hard to write an exporter, the file format specification is simple enough: http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~hwshen/581/Site/Lab3_files/Labhelp_Obj_parser.htm